# save canvas as an image on local machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to save canvas on my local machine but nothing is working . please check below code .

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }

    </style>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>
    <img id="canvasImg" alt="Right click to save me!">
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


       var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);

       // draw cloud
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(170, 80);
      context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
      context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
      context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
      context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
      context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
      context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);
      context.closePath();
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
      context.fill();
      context.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';
      context.stroke();
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';

      var imageData = canvas.toDataURL();


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

in this example code i am draing some image and cloud and wish to save it as as image file ???

Comment: You cannot save a canvas which has been "tainted" by images from a different domain. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image

Answer (score 1):

As Sacho mentioned, 'tainting a canvas stops it being saved. [This is a security feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image) to stop data from third-party websites being captured.

One workaround is to serve up all static images from your own website. This can be done by having your server download the image on request from the third-party site and return the data stream (as if it was on your own domain). Then the browser has no complaints about tainting as it is effectively from your server.

*I have no idea what your server-side technology is, so can't suggest a specific implementation, but you basically could generate requests like:*

```
/imagerequest.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.html5canvastutorials.com%2Fdemos%2Fassets%2Fdarth-vader.jpg
```

Where the source URL is provided as a parameter and imagerequest.php (or aspx) etc is your server script.

Answer (score 0):

Try send your `imageData` to server via `XMLHTTPRequest` or `fetch`. Something like this:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('cvs');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.font = '26pt Arial';
context.fillText('Some example text!', 10, 40);

url = canvas.toDataURL();
fetch('/yoururl', { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(url)})
.then(res => console.log(res))
```

Maybe [this link](http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/april/an-example-of-the-html5-canvas-todataurl-function.html) helps too

Comment: Post some code. If in future this link may get invalid reference then your post will not be an proper answer.